# Cual es la diferencia entre los archivos configure.py y setup.py?

Tags: python

tengo una duda con respecto a los archivos configure.py y setup.py que suelen estar presentes en el código fuente de módulos o paquetes de Python..a lo que voy es,cual es la diferencia entre ambos..ya que la manera de proceder con los configure.py es ejecutar Python configure.py , luego make y finalmente make install..con los setup.py cual sería el procedimiento? Desde ya gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Lo más probable si hay un `setup.py` es que se trate de un paquete que sigue el formato estándar para ser instalado con `pip`, por lo que podrías hacer `pip install .` Es también bastante probable que ese paquete esté publicado en PyPI por lo que ni necesites bajarlo e instalarlo "a mano" sino que un `pip install paquete` directo ya funcione. Esto tiene la ventaja de que si además el paquete proporciona una versión binaria ya compilada para tu operativo, la instalación será mucho más rápida al no depender de compiladores y bibliotecas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalmente, para realizar la configuración del entorno antes de la compilación se usan herramientas como autotools o cmake, algo farragosas de utilizar. En python se opta por usar [`configure.py`](https://github.com/hotgloupi/configure.py), más fácil y que no requiere usar nada más que python.

Por otra parte, `setup.py` contiene metainformación para crear el paquete python, con instrucciones de compilación y listado de dependencias de otros módulos. Este fichero es interpretado por [setuptools](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools) para crear y publicar el paquete. `Setuptools` es la herramienta que usa `pip` para instalar paquetes.

Es muy posible que `setuptools` use `configure.py` para configurar la compilación. Pero puede ser que, aún con todo, sea necesario ajustar a mano los parámetros de `configure.py` según la plataforma y versión de python que vayas a usar. Para evitar problemas, el repositorio [pypi.org](https://pypi.org) guarda paquetes compilados para distintas plataformas y versiones que puede usar `setuptools` para evitar tener que compilarlo.